# How to display wordpress login form on index.html home page?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have an existing HTML website. And then Wordpress installed on a separate folder. Wordpress has login, and content .. How can I display the Wordpress login form on my main index.HTML page ? and so once logged in from home, it would redirect to the Wordpress logged in sections ???

Comment: Please NOTE** I'm trying to show the login form OUTSIDE OF WORDPRESS, os a separate HTML home page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an `index.php` instead of an `index.html` file. That will allow you to use [WordPress functions outside of WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files). That would then allow you to put [`<?php wp_login_form(); ?>`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) wherever you want the form to go.

Otherwise you'll have to copy the HTML output of the current login form and paste it into the html file.